# Goroutine deadlock

Tags: go, goroutine

the following goroutine code returns deadlock...

Please help me to identify the issue
package main

```
import "fmt"

func main() {
    // create & consume channel
    counter := make(chan int)
    even := make(chan int)
    odd := make(chan int)
    square := make(chan int)
    merge := make(chan int)
    out := make(chan struct{})

    //GoRoutines
    go counterFn(counter)
    go squarerFn(counter, square)
    go counterSplit(counter, even, odd)
    go merger(square, odd, merge)
    go printOut(merge, out)
    <-out
}

func counterFn(counter chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        counter <- i
    }
    close(counter)
}

func squarerFn(counter chan int, square chan int) {
    for i := range counter {
        square <- i * i
    }
    close(square)
}

func counterSplit(counter chan int, even chan int, odd chan int) {
    for i := range counter {
        if i%2 == 0 {
            even <- i
        } else {
            odd <- i
        }
    }
    close(even)
    close(odd)
}

func merger(even chan int, odd chan int, merge chan int) {
    i := 0
    for {
        fmt.Printf("%d \n", i)
        a, ok := <-even
        if !ok {
            i++
        } else {
            merge <- a
        }
        a, ok = <-odd
        if !ok {
            i++
        } else {
            merge <- a
        }
        if i == 2 {
            break
        }
    }
    close(merge)
}

func printOut(merge chan int, out chan struct{}) {
    for i := range merge {
        fmt.Print(i)
    }
    close(out)
}
```

Here is the output

```
go run channel_pipelineAdv.go
0 , 0
1
0 , 9
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
        D:/channel_pipelineAdv.go:20 +0x233

goroutine 7 [chan send]:
main.squarerFn(0x0?, 0x0?)
        D:/channel_pipelineAdv.go:32 +0x45
created by main.main in goroutine 1
        D:/channel_pipelineAdv.go:16 +0x114

goroutine 8 [chan send]:
main.counterSplit(0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?)
        D:/channel_pipelineAdv.go:40 +0x5e
created by main.main in goroutine 1
        D:/channel_pipelineAdv.go:17 +0x179

goroutine 9 [chan receive]:
main.merger(0x0?, 0x0?, 0x0?)
        D:/channel_pipelineAdv.go:59 +0xca
created by main.main in goroutine 1
        D:/channel_pipelineAdv.go:18 +0x1d9

goroutine 10 [chan receive]:
main.printOut(0x0?, 0x0?)
        D:/channel_pipelineAdv.go:73 +0x77
created by main.main in goroutine 1
        D:/channel_pipelineAdv.go:19 +0x227
exit status 2
PS D:\Study\Go\GoLearn\basic>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: To sync multiply goroutine on when they have finish, you should use a WaitGroup (https://gobyexample.com/waitgroups).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the code of `merger` is problematic: its relying on incrementing of `i` up to a limit of 2 appears to be based on the expectation that both `even` and `odd` are closed roughly at the same time, and then a read from `even` returning `false` as its second value will be followed by a read from `odd`–also returning `false` as its second value.

This expectation is unfounded: any goroutine might get "stalled" for whatever reason which would make other goroutines do "more" progress.

Think what happens if the goroutine sending to `odd` gets way less computing quanta than that sending to `even`.
In this scenario, suppose that `even` is closed, and `odd` is not and there will be two or more sends (and matching receives) performed on it. The loop in `merger` will execute a "no-op" receive from the closed `even` and increment `i` by one, then a "true" receive from `odd` (and not touch `i`), then another successful "no-op" receive from `even` and bump `i` to 2, and then another "true" receive from `odd` and then exit as `i` is 2 even though there may be more sends to be done over `odd`.

We could fix your code by employing an idiom of using the `switch` statement operating on more than a single channel in a loop combined with "disabling" the channels which are "known to be done with":

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    // create & consume channel
    counter := make(chan int)
    even := make(chan int)
    odd := make(chan int)
    square := make(chan int)
    merge := make(chan int)
    out := make(chan struct{})

    //GoRoutines
    go counterFn(counter)
    go squarerFn(counter, square)
    go counterSplit(counter, even, odd)
    go merger(square, odd, merge)
    go printOut(merge, out)
    <-out
}

func counterFn(counter chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        counter <- i
    }
    close(counter)
}

func squarerFn(counter chan int, square chan int) {
    for i := range counter {
        square <- i * i
    }
    close(square)
}

func counterSplit(counter chan int, even chan int, odd chan int) {
    for i := range counter {
        if i%2 == 0 {
            even <- i
        } else {
            odd <- i
        }
    }
    close(even)
    close(odd)
}

func merger(even chan int, odd chan int, merge chan int) {
    for {
        select {
        case a, ok := <-even:
            if ok {
                merge <- a
            } else {
                even = nil
            }
        case b, ok := <-odd:
            if ok {
                merge <- b
            } else {
                odd = nil
            }
        default:
            close(merge)
            return
        }
    }
}

func printOut(merge chan int, out chan struct{}) {
    for i := range merge {
        fmt.Print(i)
    }
    close(out)
}
```

([Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/gZUHiHUSTyV).)

Note that there, once we're done with `even`, we overwrite it with `nil` which will make the next attempt to read from it [block indefinitely](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/03/19/channel-axioms), in effect making `select` always prefer another branch–if any. Eventually disabling `odd` in the same way (by now, you should understand that `odd` might as well get closed earlier than `even`, I'm just continuing the first part of the explanation) will make `select` prefer the only remaining branch, `default`, which will make it close the resulting channel and exit.